# Kraken Dehydration preventing using Environmental Protection

Tags: savage-worlds, 50-fathoms

In 50 Fathoms Kraken and a few other races have a hindrance of Dehydration, that means they must immerse themselfs in water for at at least hour, in every 24 hours, can the dehdyration be prevented using the Enviromental Protection spell?

Comment: What happens to the Kraken if they don't immerse themselves for an hour each day?

Comment: They suffer a automatic Fatigue each day they do not immerse themself's, until they are incapacitated, and then they die.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wording of the Environmental Protection power states that it:

> Allows the target to speak, breathe and move at his normal Pace in one
>   normally harmful environment.

As Kraken experience environments out of water as harmful, I would rule that the power protects them in the same way as it would a human who was underwater.

The one caveat to this is that the power would need to be constantly active during the day.  If you wanted to get fiddly, you could rule that if it were active half the day, the Kraken would only need half an hour in water and so on, but this could very quickly get difficult to track.

Comment: +1: I'd agree that **protection** is only a fraction as effective as **immersion**.

Comment: So, will the GM allow you to build. with the appropriate magical tools, an **Environmental Protection Suit (Kraken)**?